# Fatal Error when loading Catalog-settings in backend

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

On a fresh 1.5.0.1 Magento install when choosing Catalog from the settings->settings menu I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO' in
>   */my-install-dir*/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Price/Step.php on line 33

Checked `Step.php` and it does not look damaged and contains the following:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Price_Step
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
               'value' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO,
               'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Automatic')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::RANGE_CALCULATION_MANUAL,
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manual')
            ),
        );
    }

}`
```

Anyone know this error or how to fix it?

Comment: Line 33: 'value' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO,

Comment: Have you looked at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`? Does it have a constant called `RANGE_CALCULATIOON_AUTO`?

Comment: @Joseph yes in mage/catalog/model/layer/filter/price.php it says:
`const RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO    = 'auto';`

Answer (score 6):

PHP is complaining that it can't find the constant on `RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO` defined on the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`

Based on your comments above, it sounds like you already checked the file at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
```

to ensure is had the correct constant defined.

```
const RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO    = 'auto';
```

Based on that, my guess would be there's a **different** Price.php being loaded for this class.  This can happen if

1. Someone's placed a different version in `community` or `local`
2. Someone's monkied with the include path beyond Magento's normal monkey business

Check for files at

```
app/community/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
app/local/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
```

If that doesn't work, add some temporary debugging code to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Price/Step.php
```

that uses reflection to figure out what file PHP is loading the class from

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Price_Step
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        //NEW LINES HERE
        $r = new ReflectionClass('Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price');
        var_dump($r->getFileName());
        //echo $r->getFileName(); // if too long for var_dump
        exit("Bailing at line ".__LINE__." in ".__FILE__);
        //END NEW LINES
        return array(
            array(
               'value' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::RANGE_CALCULATION_AUTO,
               'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Automatic')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::RANGE_CALCULATION_MANUAL,
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manual')
            ),
        );
    }

}`
```

This will dump out a file path that points to the exact place PHP is loading the class from, which should get you where you need to go.